# Connect to a device's SSH on a network that has no inbound traffic enabled and no static IP address

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, private-network

what I'm trying to do is to enable a **Raspberry**, physically placed in a client's site, that **has** internet access via **Dynamic IP**, to receive SSH commands from the wild **without having to manipulate the client's router and firewall**. No Inbound connections allowed on that network, plus, the internet address of the Client's site is dynamic.

***Edit***: to know the solution for this problem, refer to the replies of **Kevin_Kinsey** and **Florin Godard**, or scroll to the end of my question to know how I was able to get it working on non-standard SSH port 22.

I've already tried to study and understand what's proposed on [ssh to private-ip on Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87432/ssh-to-private-ip), but I'm really not getting the point.

I do want to connect from my, say, **laptop**, to the Client's **VPS server**, and make the VPS server connect to the **Raspberry** SSH. So:

```
           ( firewall access allow in+out )
      | =>           VPS Server              \    ( firewall access allow out only )
      |                                      | =>    Raspberry
MY PC /
```

Here is it a **case scenario** with given IP adresses, ports and names configurations:

```
MY PC 
    name: mypc@local.lan

Client VPS Server
    name: remote.null.tld
    IP Address: 98.76.54.32
    SSH Port: 9876

Raspberry
    model: Zero W
    name: raspi1@clientlocal.lan
    IP Address: dynamic IP ( based on Internet Provider )
    SSH Port: 6789
    Raspberry's iptables: empty
    Router's Firewall Restrictions: allow only out
    Internet stability: very low
```

The Raspberry's external IP is the one assigned from the Internet Provider, and may vary depending on router restarts. Cannot determine it absolutely.

Internet Access on the client's network is **really unstable**. Radio link or something like that. Anyway, internet connection suffers of very dancing bandwidth.

Plus, the Client's router cannot be manipulated not because of laziness but because of restrictions imposed by the Client's IT dep.

I do have SSH access to the Client's VPS and I'm able to install whatever software on it.

Edit: **solution to the problem**

On my configuration, ports were non-standard. So, the solution was this one:

On the Raspberry:

```
# login to username@remote.null.tld is done via private/public key with no passwords
ssh -p 9876 -f -N -T -R 55555:localhost:6789 username@remote.null.tld
```

On the Raspberry's crontab:

```
# A re-connect is performed at every 10th minute of every hour to prevent accidental tunnel breakdowns.
10 * * * * ps -ef | grep 'ssh -p 9876 -f -N -T -R' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9 && sleep 30s && ssh -p 9876 -f -N -T -R 55555:localhost:6789 username@remote.null.tld >/dev/null 2>&1
```

On the bridge VPS *remote.null.tld*

```
ssh -p 55555 raspberry_username@localhost
```

Or, a more elegant solution via modifying the VPS's ssh config:

```
Host tunnelToRemoteRaspberry
    Hostname localhost
    User raspberry_username
    Port 55555
```

Comment: I'd take a look at having the RPi run a cronjob that SSH'es out to a known server and port forwards on that known machine (the "-L" switch) ... you could then connect to that port on the server and be inside the RPi.

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey can you please expand on your kind suggestion based on my question's case scenario config?

Comment: Been a long time since I had this working ... I will look & see what I can dig up.

Comment: Look up "reverse port forwarding" on A Major Search Engine.  I found an entry in the blog at "devolutions dot net" that looks promising.

Comment: I've attempted to encapsulate this concept in an answer, below.

Comment: Use outbound SSH with remote port forwarding, to set up a port on your server that tunnels back to the Pi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible.  Use *"reverse port forwarding"*.  You'll probably need a cronjob set up to check if it's connected.  If not, run something like this:

```
ssh -f -N -T -R 2210:localhost:22 me@example.com
```

*"Example.com"* is some server outside the FW that you do have access to.  You're forwarding port 22 on the RPi to port 2210 on `example.com`.  You can then SSH into example.com and do:

```
ssh RaspberryUser@localhost -p 2210
```

And you'll be connected to the RPi box.

Comment: As for what the cronjob/test would look like, there are probably a lot of way to skin that cat.

Comment: I've been able to manage to get it working by merging your reply with the one of Florin Godard. Thank you for your time!

Comment: What does `FW` mean? And `RPi`?

Comment: Context?  Firewall, Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming the user names `remote` on the VPS and `pi` on the raspberry.

1. You choose a free port on the VPS. A random five-digit value below 65000 should work.
2. On the Raspberry, you run

   ```
   ssh -R PORT:localhost:22 remote@vps
   ```
3. On the VPS, you connect to the Raspberry with

   ```
   ssh -p PORT pi@localhost
   ```

Replace the PORT with the port you have chosen in the first step.

In step 2, you create a reverse tunnel from the PORT on the VPS to port 22 on the Raspberry, which is where the Raspberry's SSH server listens. In step 3, you connect to the PORT on the VPS and get transferred to the port 22 on the Raspberry.

You can then configure a connection inside the VPS' ~/.ssh/config such as:

```
Host raspberryTunnel
  Hostname localhost
  User pi
  Port PORT
```

If that works reliably, you can replace the single SSH connection on the Raspberry with autossh, which will automatically recreate the connection when it goes down.

```
autossh -R PORT:localhost:22 remote@vps
```

Comment: Thank you Florin, I've tried to simulate what you suggest by:
On the Raspberry: 
    ssh -p 9876 -R 63876:localhost:9876  myuser@remote.null.tld
On the VPS: 
    ssh raspberryTunnel ( after editing the .ssh/config file )

On the Raspi side, I'm able to make an SSH connection to the VPS.
On the VPS side, while trying to connect, i get:
    myuser@localhost's password:

Providing the myuser's password gives a "Permission denied, please try again.". Unfortunately I'm not understanding what's happening under the hood :(

Comment: @Maurizio note that if the username is not same on VPS and rpi, you will have to specify it... for example step2 would be `ssh -R PORT:localhost:22 vpsuser@vps` and step3 `ssh -p PORT raspi1@localhost`. Also you must enter vps password in step2, and raspberryPi password in step3.

Comment: Admittedly, it is a bit confusing. What happens is that the SSH command from the raspberry open a reverse tunnel from PORT on the VPS to port 22 on the Raspberry. So when you connect to the PORT on the VPS, you get actually connected to port 22 on the Raspberry, where the SSH server listens. So, as Matija said, you need to set the correct users, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @FlorinGodard I've been able to manage to get it working by merging your reply with the one of Kevin_Kinsey. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do *exactly as you ask* is impossible:

> No Inbound connections allowed on that network

However, you can easily:

- have the Pi  make an outbound connection to your laptop [using reverse SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work) that you [schedule](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16093/how-can-i-tell-cron-to-run-a-command-every-other-day-odd-even)
- `ssh` from your laptop  to the VPS server and from the VPS server `ssh` again to the Pi

Comment: Thank you Fabby, would you try and give me an advice on how to for the two methods you suggested?

Comment: If @Maurizio has outbound access, he can create a reverse SSH tunnel to a machine on the Internet and then connect back to the PI through that SSH connection. It is not impossible, it is only impossible to initiate the connection from the outside to the inside.

Comment: @Maurizio Clarified answer. (*Prego....* **;-)** )

Comment: @number9 Clarified answer.

Comment: This. We had pretty much the same scenario and the device would just be set up to "dial home" every hour or so (could be configured) to pick up any new instructions. Where feasible it would maintain a VPN connection to home, and with that in play you could SSH using its IP on the VPN. It was flaky but that's literally the best you can do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the (up)vote of confidence...  **0:-)**

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, you can reach your goal only with maintenance connections from the device to a server you maintain.

What exactly these connections consist of can be different:

- connect, fetch tasks to execute and proceed with them.
- connect to a VPN and be part of that, allowing to be connected to
- connect via SSH and establish a tunnel connection

Usable protocols

- VPN (uses several ports)
- SSH
- HTTPS
- even UUCP, although a little bit outdated

Depending on what the customer allows inside their network, you can even implement several of these methods to then choose from.

Each method has its pros and cons.

- SSH:

  - +: only one port needed
  - -: maybe not every network allows outbound SSH connections
- VPN:

  - +: easiest integration into server's network
  - -: several ports needed
  - -: maybe not every network allows outbound SSH connections
- HTTPS:

  - +: probably supported
  - -: no real command line, only "work packages" are sendable
  - -: big effort needed to set up
- UUCP:

  - +: allows batches to be sent
  - -: outdated protocol

Comment: what do you suggest is the best approach based on my question's case scenario config?

Comment: @Maurizio As said, that depends on what the customer allows.

Answer (score 1):

If Pi firewall doesn't allow incoming connections then there is no way to establish connection. Your only way is to punch a hole through a firewall by using established connections.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out [ZeroTier](http://zerotier.com/): it lets you set up a virtual network with the rules you want, e.g., that any node can directly connect to any other node. They handle all kinds of connectivity issues under the hood, including relaying traffic through their servers if needed.